# Refactoring/Modifying an Interface and Auto-update all the referencing classes/interfaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Before posting this question I spent almost 3 hours looking for the similar questions. the closest that I found was asking how to [Prevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762940/how-to-prevent-having-to-update-all-implementing-classes-after-updating-an-inter) this. but I'm looking for a way to do it automatically.I have an interface which has been implemented in multiple classes. when I'm adding a another property to that interface I have to go and update all the references. I was wondering if there's anyway to auto-implement that field in all the classes/interfaces that have implemented that interface? similar to when you refactor a method name and all of its references will be updated with the new name!
let's say I add `MyProperty` to an interface, the following is expected to be auto-generated in all its references.

```cs
public string MyProperty {get; set;}
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the expected implementation? All I can think of is `throw new NotImplementedException();`, but that just moves the error from compile-time to runtime--usually you try for the opposite.

Comment: @31eee384 thorw new NotImplementedException() is for methods. I'm looking for the properties. my expected implementation is similar to C# Auto-Implemented Properties.  Thank you

Comment: It's good to know that you want auto-properties to be generated, but it's not true that `NotImplementedException` is for methods. By default Visual Studio fills in a non-implemented property with `public int MyProperty { get { throw new NotImpl...(); } set { throw new NotImpl...(); } }` (I do this by putting the cursor over the red-squigglied interface, pressing control+., and selecting "Implement interface".) Do you have Resharper?

Comment: @31eee384  Yeah, doing it manually, I have to go to every single reference and right click on the Interface name and click onImplement interface. and it will add the missing properties with NotImplementedException. however there's a way that you can change it so instead of   NotImplementedException , it will put  get; set; which is explained [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703277/how-can-i-make-implementation-of-an-interface-produce-an-auto-property-instead-o#) and no I don't have ReSharper.

Comment: Ok, sorry I couldn't be any help. Maybe you should add that extra info to your question, though: that you want to implement the properties as `get; set`. (Backticks/grave accents (\`) for code formatting, by the way.)

Comment: @31eee384 `thank you`